# Additional data in dependency injection

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependency-injection

I have a code like the below:

```
class ISaver(abc.ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def save(self, text):
        pass

class FileSaver(ISaver):
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath  # <----- This part is important, please remember it

    def save(self, text):
        with open(self.filepath, 'w') as file:
            file.write(text)

class Scraper1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_saver = FileSaver('one.html')  # <----- And this

    def scrape(self, url):
        res = requests.get('https://example.com')
        self.file_saver.save(res.content)

class Scraper2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_saver = FileSaver('two.html')  # <----- And this

    def scrape(self, url):
        res = requests.get('https://anotherexample.com')
        self.file_saver.save(res.content)
```

Now I want to pass `FileSaver` into `Scraper` through the [python dependency injector library](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org).

The result should be something like this:

```
class DIContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    file_saver = providers.Factory(FileSaver)  # <----- I don't want to pass the filepath here

class Scraper1:
    def __init__(self, file_saver = Provide[DIContainer.file_saver]):
        self.file_saver = file_saver  # <----- How should I pass the filepath here
    .
    .
    .

class Scraper2:
    def __init__(self, file_saver = Provide[DIContainer.file_saver]):
        self.file_saver = file_saver  # <----- Or here?
    .
    .
    .
```

I can't write the `filepath` in the line that I mentioned, because it's related to the project scenario. But I need this variable in `Scraper1` and `Scraper2`.

Can anyone help me for fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a filepath setter and call that from within Scraper1? Although this is no longer follows the DI pattern; the filepath is a dependency of Scraper1, so it should be injected in to it.

```
from dependency_injector import containers, providers
import abc

class ISaver(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def save(self, text):
        pass

class FileSaver(ISaver):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filepath = None

    def set_filepath(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath

    def save(self, text):
        print(f"writing {text} to {self.filepath}")
        with open(self.filepath, 'w') as file:
            file.write(text)

class Scraper1:
    def __init__(self, file_saver):
        self.file_saver = file_saver
        self.file_saver.set_filepath('foo/bar')

class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    file_saver = providers.Factory(FileSaver)
    file_scraper = providers.Factory(Scraper1, file_saver)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    container = Container()
    container.wire(modules=[__name__])
    file_scraper = container.file_scraper()
    file_scraper.file_saver.save("hello")
```